# Form submit sending POST request instead GET

Tags: html, django, get, get-request

I'm trying to make `django-filter` work, and it have worked, but now it suddenly have stopped.

The issue is that the `submit` button in the filter seems to be sending a POST request and not GET

Below is a snippet of the HTML code

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form|crispy}}
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Add product</button>
</div>


<div id="filter-menu">
        <form method="get">
          {{filter.form.nick_name|as_crispy_field}}
          <br>
          {{filter.form.domain|as_crispy_field}}
          <br>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Filtrér</button>
        </form>
        
        <form method="get">
          {{filter.form.nick_name|as_crispy_field}}
          <br>
          {{filter.form.domain|as_crispy_field}}
          <br>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Dummy</button>
          </form>
</div>
```

I do have a POST-request submit button above as seen, and it seems like it's the one being triggerd, since when I debug the application, `request.method == "POST"` when pressing the `apply filter` button.

The funny thing is that the "dummy button" works without an issue

Comment: At first glance your first form doesn't have closing `</form>` tag.

Comment: It does - after the button

Comment: No in the code you showed here.

Comment: Aaaah, in the POST-method. You are completely right - how did I miss that! THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Simple isn't it? The top form has post method and u forgot to add  for it.. Use below code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form|crispy}}
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Add product</button>
</form>
</div>


<div id="filter-menu">
        <form method="get">
          {{filter.form.nick_name|as_crispy_field}}
          <br>
          {{filter.form.domain|as_crispy_field}}
          <br>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Filtrér</button>
        </form>
        
        <form method="get">
          {{filter.form.nick_name|as_crispy_field}}
          <br>
          {{filter.form.domain|as_crispy_field}}
          <br>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Dummy</button>
          </form>
</div>
```

What the problem must be is that it is assuming all the other forms as part of the first form which is only form with post method. That's why u r getting post results. Hope it helps. Pls vote the answer if it does.

Comment: Did it help? Yes?